# Exported format file is empty

Tags: intellij-idea

IntelliJ IDEA 2023.2.5 (Community Edition)

I want to share my file formatter between all members of java project. As result we can use **SAME** java formmater.

So I try to export my file formatter like this:

```
File -> Settings -> Code style -> Scheme = Default
```

And then

```
Export -> IntelliJ IDEA code style XML
```

Here result file:

```
<code_scheme name="Default" version="173" />
```

Why this file is empty?

P.S.
If I export like this:

```
Export -> Eclipse XML profile
```

The result is OK (file is not empty).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<profiles version="21">
    <profile kind="CodeFormatterProfile" name="Default" version="21">
        <setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.tabulation.char" value="space"/>
        <setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.use_tabs_only_for_leading_indentations" value="false"/>
        <setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.indentation.size" value="4"/>
        <setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.tabulation.size" value="4"/>
        <setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.text_block_indentation" value="0"/>
        <setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.indent_body_declarations_compare_to_type_header" value="true"/>
        <setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.indent_body_declarations_compare_to_enum_declaration_header" value="true"/>
        <setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.indent_body_declarations_compare_to_enum_constant_header" value="true"/>
        <setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.indent_body_declarations_compare_to_annotation_declaration_header" value="true"/>
        <setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.indent_body_declarations_compare_to_record_header" value="true"/>
...
```

Comment: Can you ask yourself:  How can anyone, who is reading this, know what contents you expected ?  Please re-read: [How do I ask a question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: "Why this file is empty?"  vs, "The result is OK (file is not empty).", Pleas re-read: [How do I ask a question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here. We fix it by just exporting and importing the Eclipse XML formatter (even though we are using Intellij IDEA, it still works perfectly) so that our team could follow the same code style.

Just make sure to choose the right style for your favorite project and you're good to go

Answer (score 0):

IDE just saves this as diff from default codestyle.

Comment: I need to use SAME formatter in all members of java team. So I want to export code formatter to file. Is it possible?